# When people try to buy something with Paypal Snadbox they can't login

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to set up a donation script for my game. I have one a friend of mine let me use. It apparently is all working (But wasnt). Whenever they open up the page in there Steam Overlay it brings them to " https://www.sandbox.paypal.com " and when they try to login to send me money it will not let them log into there Paypal account. I have had multiple people try. Non of them could log in.

Comment: well um its the sandbox, its not for real use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use test payments in the sandbox environment with special sandbox customer accounts which need to be setup by the sandbox Business account holder. Your regular paypal accounts will not work.

Have fun,
Frank